# ReactJS, trying to insert url image into database when uploading a file

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to get get the URL from an upload from firebase in reactJS, then insert it into my clients object with the URL tag?

```
handleUploadSuccess = filename => {
  this.setState({ avatar: filename, progress: 100, isUploading: false });
  firebase
    .storage()
    .ref("images")
    .child(filename)
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => this.setState({ avatarURL: url } ))
    .then(function(snapshot)
    {
      const url = snapshot.getDownloadURL();
      const clientRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
      const clientsData = {
        companyName: this.companyName.value,
        ID: this.state.ID,
        URL: url


      }
    });
```

};

Comment: `getDownloadURL()` returns a promise (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL), so I don't think that `snapshot.getDownloadURL();` would work. You shoulk use the url you get in `.then(url => this.setState({ avatarURL: url } ))` to write to the database.

Comment: perfect thanks got it worked